# How to flip the sign of a float using bitwise operators in C

Tags: c, floating-point, bitwise-operators

This is the code I have so far

```
// given the 32 bits of a float return it with its sign flipped
uint32_t sign_flip(uint32_t f) {
    int mask = 1;    
    f = ~f; // 1's Complement 
    while (mask > 0 && (mask & f)) 
    { 
        f ^= mask; 
        mask <<= 1; 
    } 
    f ^= mask; // 2's complment 
    return f; // REPLACE ME WITH YOUR CODE
}
```

Expected output:

```
./sign_flip -42
sign_flip(-42) returned 42
```

output:

```
./sign_flip -42
sign_flip(-42) returned 0.10546875
```

How would I go about fixing this? I am not sure what the issue is

Comment: Why `float`? It looks you are performing an integer operation.

Comment: How would I flip just the sign bit of a float? that is my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IEEE 754 floating-point format is not 2's complement. Just flip most-significant bit:

```c
float f = 42;
*(uint32_t*)&f ^= (1 << 31);
printf("%f\n", f);
```

Comment: I have tried this it gives an error that left shift of 1 by 31 places cannot be represented in type 'int'

Comment: Try `(1ULL << 31)`

Comment: This will not work on big-endian systems. The format of IEEE 754 is independent of endianness. Not only that, but this is a strict aliasing violation. More correct would be `*(uint8_t*)&f ^= 0x80;` (assuming you are on a system with 8-bit bytes).

Comment: @paddy: Floating-point formats are not independent of endianness. IEEE 754 does not specify the order of bytes stored in memory for floating-point formats, so implementations may choose either endianness (or even other byte orders). The storage order of bytes for floating-point formats typically mirrors the storage order of bytes for integers on the same platform.

Comment: @paddy as i know, IEEE 754 is designed to allow correct comparison as signed integers. Sign bit always corresponds to integer sign, exponent bits are most significant than digits.

Comment: @EricPostpischil "The storage order of bytes for floating-point formats typically mirrors the storage order of bytes for integers on the same platform" --> Usually true, yet not required by C and real opposite orders for integer/FP exist.

Comment: @dimich `(1UL << 31)` (one `L`) would be sufficient.

Comment: @dimich "Sign bit always corresponds to integer sign"  is not specified by C.

Answer (score 1):

It is reasonable to expect a `float` to have a single isolated sign bit regardless of encoding, [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) or not.

Find that bit and use it to flip the `float` sign bit.  Do not assume its location.  No need to assume common endian-ness of `float/uint32_t` - which is not required by C.  Use a `union` to avoid strict aliasing violations instead of pointer tricks.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t sign_flip(uint32_t f) {
  assert(sizeof(float) == sizeof(uint32_t));
  static const union {
    uint32_t u32;
    float f;
  } plus1 = { .f = 1.0f }, minus1 = { .f = -1.0f };
  //          v--------------------v Sign bit 
  return f ^ (plus1.u32 ^ minus1.u32);
}
```